# Code for getting SEO friendly in htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am new to htaccess file and have the following requirement.

I have a dynamic page which handles like this

```
    com/index.php?postname=products
    .com/index.php?cat=news&country=india
```

for these pages I want SEO friendly urls like this

```
     .com/products/      to     .com/index.php?postname=products
      .com/news/country   to    .com/index.php?cat=news&country=india
```

What code do I need to put it in htaccess file?

Do I need to write RewriteCond or RewriteRule or both?

If possible please give me the sample code to do this.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?postname=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?cat=$1&country=$2 [L]
```

Comment: I think you have a typo `phjp`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the `htaccess` code that helps you

Save the line .htaccess in your index.php folder or root folder.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_\-]+)$ index.php?postname=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_\-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_\-]+)$ index.php?cat=$1&country=$2 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
   SecFilterEngine Off
   SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on No
</IfModule>
```

It works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Example for your work.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^postname=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /postname/%1? [R=301]
RewriteRule ^postname/([^-]+)$ /postname.php?id=$1 [L]
```

The above code will redirect

```
index.php?postname=products
```

to

```
index/products
```